Using Huggingface model in onnx
I have downloaded the m2m100_418M model from huggingface and converted to onnx model. now i have 2 files, encoder.onnx and decoder.onnx. now i want to translate a text. so far i have written these codes.
public class EncoderInput
{
    [VectorType(1, 256)]
    [ColumnName("input_ids")]
    public long[] InputIds { get; set; }

    [VectorType(1, 256)]
    [ColumnName("attention_mask")]
    public long[] AttentionMask { get; set; }
}

public class DecoderInput
{
    [VectorType(1, 256)]
    [ColumnName("encoder_attention_mask")]
    public long[] EncoderAttensionMask { get; set; }

    [VectorType(1, 256)]
    [ColumnName("input_ids")]
    public long[] InputIds { get; set; }



    [VectorType(1, 256)]
    [ColumnName("encoder_hidden_states")]
    public float[] EncoderHiddenState { get; set; }

}

    var source = "I love you";
var tokenizer = new BertMultilingualTokenizer();
var encoded = tokenizer.Encode(256, source);
// Create a new instance of the InferenceSession

var encoderInput = new EncoderInput()
{
    InputIds = encoded.Select(t => t.InputIds).ToArray(),
    AttentionMask = encoded.Select(t => t.AttentionMask).ToArray(),
};

using var inputIdsOrtValue = OrtValue.CreateTensorValueFromMemory(encoderInput.InputIds,
      new long[] { 1, encoderInput.InputIds.Length });

using var attMaskOrtValue = OrtValue.CreateTensorValueFromMemory(encoderInput.AttentionMask,
      new long[] { 1, encoderInput.AttentionMask.Length });


var encoder = new InferenceSession("./onnx/m2m100_418M/encoder_model.onnx");
var decoder = new InferenceSession("./onnx/m2m100_418M/decoder_model.onnx");

var encoderInputs = new Dictionary<string, OrtValue>
{
    { "input_ids", inputIdsOrtValue },
    { "attention_mask", attMaskOrtValue },
};

using var runOptions = new RunOptions();

using var encoderOutput = encoder.Run(runOptions, encoderInputs, encoder.OutputNames);

var t = encoderOutput.First().GetTensorTypeAndShape();

var decoderInput = new DecoderInput()
{
    InputIds = encoded.Select(t => t.InputIds).ToArray(),
    EncoderAttensionMask = encoded.Select(t => t.AttentionMask).ToArray(),
    EncoderHiddenState = encoderOutput.First().GetTensorDataAsSpan<float>().ToArray()
};

using var hiddenState = OrtValue.CreateTensorValueFromMemory(decoderInput.EncoderHiddenState,
      new long[] { 1, decoderInput.EncoderHiddenState.Length / 1024, 1024 });

var decoderInputs = new Dictionary<string, OrtValue>
{
    { "encoder_attention_mask", attMaskOrtValue },
    { "input_ids", inputIdsOrtValue },
    { "encoder_hidden_states", hiddenState },
};


using var decoderOutput = decoder.Run(runOptions, decoderInputs, decoder.OutputNames);

i use BertTokenizer open source library to tokenize and Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime in C#.
how can i complete my code and get the result. also how can i specify target language for translation in this setup. actually my goal is to get a text and target language and then translate it to that target.
I converted hugging face model to onnx and i wanted to translate text to any language
